# Flexbox grid layout - animate items width

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to build a grid with some items (tiles) that show information about team members.

The layout has 3 columns and an unlimited amount of rows.

Assumptions:

- In the beginning, each tile has 33.3% width (3column layout).
- When we click a tile title, then the clickable item will occupy 2 columns in its row (66.6% width)
- The clickable item has never gone to the next row (no wrap), elements from column 1 and 2 should have smooth animate width from left to right.
- If it is an element from column 3, then the animation width should be increased from the right edge to left, and the previous element (from column 2) should go to the beginning in the next row
- The item width should be animated

(1) Default grid example (with 9 closed tiles):

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

(2) Grid with open 4th tile (takes column 1 and 2; move the next elements):

```
1 2 3
4 4 5
6 7 8 
9
```

(3) Grid with open 5th tile (takes column 2 and 3; move the next elements to the new row):

```
1 2 3
4 5 5
6 7 8
9
```

(4) Grid with open 6th tile (takes column 3 and 2 (merge right to left); move element from column 2 to the beginning next row and move elements):

```
1 2 3
4 6 6
5 7 8
9
```

The questions:

- What is the better CSS method to achieve described effect display: flex or display: grid ?
- How to achieve animation smooth effect (also when we need wrap elements to the next row)?
- How can I create the effect for open tiles from column 3 (example (4) animation goes from right to left) and move the previous element to the next row?

My current code:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'h2', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -15px;
}

.grid__item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid__item.active {
  flex: 0 0 66.66666%;
  max-width: 66.66666%;
}

.grid__item-inner {
  background: #9c9b9b;
  height: 50px;
}

h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">
      <h2>Name 1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">
      <h2>Name 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">
      <h2>Name 3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">
      <h2>Name 4</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">
      <h2>Name 5</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">
      <h2>Name 6</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">
      <h2>Name 7</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">
      <h2>Name 8</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">
      <h2>Name 9</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Neither flexbox or CSS-Grid can achieve what you require. CSS-Grid cannot animate the width change and Flexbox cannot change the order as you require.

Comment: Do you suggest any solution? What if I change order property for flexbox items? Am I able to animate 3rd column from right to left?

Comment: You can change the order BUT not in the way you suggest. You'd have to change the order for ALL the items dynamically which requires JS. Also you can't animate column changes. You've bitten off a large chunk here.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve this with CSS only. The [animate-css-grid npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/animate-css-grid) can replicate the animation you are looking for.